# SQL select with datetime conversion throws out-of-range error

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have the following SQL statement against `SQLServer 2014`

```
SELECT        SUM(payment_amount) AS Expr1, CAST(DATEPART(hour, CONVERT(datetime, sales_time, 120)) AS int) AS Expr2, CAST(DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(datetime, sales_time, 120)) AS int) AS Expr3
FROM            sales_payment
WHERE        (CAST(DATEPART(hour, CONVERT(datetime, sales_time, 120)) AS int) > 15) AND (CAST(DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(datetime, sales_time, 120)) AS int) > 30) AND (CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, date, 
                         126)) = '2016-06-14')
GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(hour, CONVERT(datetime, sales_time, 120)) AS int), CAST(DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(datetime, sales_time, 120)) AS int)
```

Basically what i am trying to achieve is to get `SUM of all payments` that was on `14th of June 2016` After `3:30 PM`.

The column `sales_time` is an `NVARCHAR` type.

However, the command works fine with all days of each month before 13th, from day 1 till day 12. But if you run 2016-06-14 it will not work while 2016-06-10 works fine.

Comment: Look at the records for the 14th... there is probably an improperly formatted date on one of the records.

Comment: Does '2016-06-15' work?

Comment: What timezone are you in?

Comment: @dazedandconfused , all the records are good, i looked to each record

Comment: @user3378165 Nope, nothing after the 12th day of each month works

Comment: @bjones +3 GMT , do i have to change any of these?

Comment: Did you try to change the monthes with the days? like this: '2016-14-06'?

Comment: @user3378165 Yes sir i did, unfortunately it didn't work, i even tried different conversion code 120,126 and 103

Comment: Did you get the same error?

Comment: I guess it would depend on where your server/application is recording these times. Or what time they are recording. Eastern Time is currently 2:42 PM 2016-06-14. So it would not be past 3:30 yet, therefore no records would be recorded.

Comment: @user3378165 Yes sir, the same error when trying any day after the 12th from any month

Comment: @bjones Thanks for your reply, well why would any other date below 12th of any month work then? it's a bit strange

Comment: In your WHERE statement, for the section below, is "date" another field in the table, or should that actually be sales_time also?

(CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, date, 126)) = '2016-06-14')

Comment: @TimLaVenice Yes sir, it is another field

Answer (score 5):

If nothing after the 12th day of each month works, it sounds suspiciously like your regional setting isn't what you think it is, and what you think is the day-portion of your datetime is actually the month portion.

Test this by trying a string like "2016-14-06" (instead of "2016-06-14") and see what you get.

By the way, this part of your query:

```
AND (CAST(DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(datetime, sales_time, 120)) AS int) > 30)
```

Means that you will not get any results between 4pm and 4:30pm.   Or 5pm - 5:30pm, and so on.   Why don't you just use one filter to get records after 3:30 on the specified date, instead of three separate filters which lead to difficulties like this?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried the 2016-14-06 also it didn't work at all.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply, i tried '2016-14-06' and also didn't work, it just gets no records at all. unlike 2016-06-12 which works fine. But once it is 2016-06-13 or any day more than 12, it throws out of range. the reason behind filters is to get records between 3:30PM and 4:00PM only

Comment: Ok, if you didn't get an error with '2016-14-06', but you DO get an error with '2016-06-13', then that just means that '2016-14-06' is the correct way to format your string, and there aren't any records on June 14.   So it would appear that this is your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, well, on the 1st till 16th i have records, but once i query 2016-05-06 it gets me 6th of May records and not the 5th of June. Strange thing

Comment: One more thing to add, if i query a date that still has not records, it doesn't throw an error, just showing the empty grid pane

Comment: If you are not getting the results you expect, but you are also not getting an error, the only way anybody could help you is if you post enough data in your question so that we can reproduce the issue on our own.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Could you please tell me which data you need and i will directly post them. Thanks a lot again for your support

Comment: At a minimum, we would need you to post a CREATE TABLE followed by INSERT statements that will create and populate a table that reproduces the behavior you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria is saying to filter out anything where the hour is greater than 3:00 PM, thus starting at 4:00 PM.  Then it is further saying, give me only records where the minutes are after 30.  So you get records starting after 4:30 PM and you only get them if they are in the second half of the hour.  One way you could check the hour and minutes is to combine them together into a single number and check if that number is greater than 1530.  Using your example, you could do something like this.

```
SELECT SUM(payment_amount) AS Expr1
    ,CAST(DATEPART(hour, CONVERT(DATETIME, sales_time, 120)) AS INT) AS Expr2
    ,CAST(DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(DATETIME, sales_time, 120)) AS INT) AS Expr3
FROM #sales_payment
WHERE (DATEPART(hour, CONVERT(DATETIME, sales_time, 120)) * 100) + CAST(DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(DATETIME, sales_time, 120)) AS INT) > 1530
AND CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(10), sales_time,120)) = '2016-06-14'
    GROUP BY CAST(DATEPART(hour, CONVERT(DATETIME, sales_time, 120)) AS INT)
        ,CAST(DATEPART(minute, CONVERT(DATETIME, sales_time, 120)) AS INT)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this command always returns out of range even if using dates below 12th of any month.